# UIViewController with closure init

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uiviewcontroller

I try to create `UIViewController`:

```
class CategoriesVC: UIViewController {
    let tableView = UITableView()
    var completionHandler: (Category)->Void?
    
    init(completionHandler: @escaping (Category)->Void) {
        super.init()
        
        self.completionHandler = completionHandler
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

and I get this error:

```
Must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'UIViewController'
```

On this line:

```
super.init()
```

Answer (score 3):

The error states clearly that you must call the designate `init` for `UIViewController`, which in this case is `super.init(nibName:,bundle:)`.

Also, the `completionHandler` syntax is wrong, here's the fix:

```
class CategoriesVC: UIViewController {
    let tableView = UITableView()
    var completionHandler: ((Category)->Void)?
    init(completionHandler: @escaping ((Category)->Void)) {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        self.completionHandler = completionHandler
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```